# Show sum at the bottom of column in mysql

Tags: mysql

Instead of using the following query to display the sum of a column at the bottom, is there another method than using the Union query

```
  select amount 
from receipt

UNION

select SUM(amount)
from receipt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) should perform exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY()`

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year
```

This gives you yearly profit without a UNION. You can also add conditionals just like in `COUNT()`